# How can I query all results matching a simple substring in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, substring

This should be so simple but I must be missing something obvious.

Table:

```
id    name
===============
1     Allison
2     BethAnn
3     Carly
4     MaryAnn
```

Test Query:

```
SELECT id,SUBSTRING(name,5) FROM my_table;
```

Result:

```
1    son
2    Ann
3    y
4    Ann
```

Great.  Now just get the id's where the characters 5+ = 'Ann':

```
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE SUBSTRING(name,5) = 'Ann';
```

Expected Result:

```
2
4
```

Instead I get nothing.  What am I missing?

Waiting for facepalm.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont see any problem there.. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af053/1

Comment: Doh!  I told you there was a facepalm coming.  I had an error in my ids where I was limiting to the wrong id.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct and producing correct results for me. There seems to be something other that is causing problem. Here is the screenshot...

[image]

Hope it helps...